# Write a signed byte to unmanaged memory using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I write a signed byte (sbyte) to unmanaged memory using VB.NET?

I can use Marshal.WriteByte() to write an unsigned byte, but there doesn't appear to be an overload for signed bytes.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a negative signed byte to an unsigned byte, XOR the absolute value with 255 and add 1.

This is call [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

So starting with -34, 
Abs(-34) -> 34, 
Xor 255 -> 221, 
+ 1 -> 222

So 222 has the same binary representation as -34.

There might be a better way to do this in the framework, but the above should work. Give it a try and let us all know.

(And it may got without saying, but a positive signed byte has the same binary representation as its unsigned conterpart. So an SByte with a value of 45 has the same representation as a Byte with value of 45).

Comment: @user1286364 Did that work for you?  Any questions, just ask.